# Mysql: CONCAT_WS('', col) vs (col is null OR col=0)

Tags: mysql, null

Is there any difference between:

- `CONCAT_WS('', column)=''`

AND

- `column is null OR column=0  *(and optionally 'OR column="" ')*`

Is one of them better/faster...?

```
SELECT my_fields FROM my_table 
WHERE my_terms_clause='anything' AND CONCAT_WS( '', nb_check ) = ''
```

OR

```
SELECT my_fields FROM my_table 
WHERE my_terms_clause='anything' AND (p.nb_check is null OR p.nb_check = 0)
```

I usually use "column is null OR column=0", but I just want "expert's tips".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use:

```
where col is null or column = 0
```

First, the intention of the code is much clearer.  Second, the function call prevents the optimizer from using an index.  To be honest,the `or` also makes it hard for the optimizer to use an index.

Probably the most efficient way to write the query is using `union all`:

```
SELECT my_fields
FROM my_table p
WHERE my_terms_clause = 'anything' AND p.nb_check is null
UNION ALL
SELECT my_fields
FROM my_table p
WHERE my_terms_clause = 'anything' AND p.nb_check = 0;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `my_table(my_terms_clause, nb_check)`.

Comment: so if I don't split the 'OR clause', indexes will not be used?

Comment: @Bast . . . You should look at the explain plan.  I find it hard to get MySQL to use indexes with `OR`.

Comment: BTW: How to split (UNION ALL in your example) where we have a group by in the query? - any other way than a sub query?

Answer (score 1):

If a column holds the value of 0, then concat_ws() with empty string as separator will return '0', not '', so the 2 expressions are not equal. If you need to check for null or 0, then better use that version, that actually checks this condition.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. But the answer from Gordon is more complete. :)

Comment: It's a different angle. If the 2 expressions do not yield the same result, then what's the point of comparing them?

Comment: I was more expecting answer about performances. But you both answered to my question. so, +1 ;)